# Filling Customer Generated dataTable with the results from a user query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, datatable

So i used datasource wizard in VS2012 to generate DataSet from my Database.

So now i am trying to fill in autogenerated datatable for each table in the database to be filled with data. However i am running into some problems.

```
string var = comboBox1.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE "+var+" LIKE "+textBox1.Text+";",connection);
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        ad.Fill(dataTable);
        ERPDataSet.ContactsDataTable dt = new ERPDataSet.ContactsDataTable(dataTable);
        contactsTableAdapter.Fill(dt);
```

So now the problem here is That when i pass Datatables into the constructor of ContactsDataTable i get the exception null reference exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

However i know for a fact that datatable is not empty.

So any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: debug it.

Long answer: inspect the *actual* command text, and then compare that to what you assume by executing it with the same credentials/authority. It is a certainty that you have an incorrect assumption.

My guess without having either the values of the table or the `var` variable in hand, is that your `LIKE` clause is functionally equivalent to an equality comparison because you are missing wildcard characters in your command text that you are assuming are present at execution or even that you are missing vital string literal single quotes.

Perhaps this would work as you expect:

`SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE {0} LIKE '%{1}%', var, textBox1.Text), connection);`

Comment: As i said i know for a fact that DataTable is not empty. This provide ample proof of it `DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select();
            foreach (var dataRow in rows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dataRow[0].ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(dataRow[1].ToString());
            }`

Comment: If you are unwilling to challenge your assumptions directly and practically by employing the debugger, you will not resolve your issue. Accepting that you have a defective assumption somewhere in your equation is the first step.

Comment: Well if the dataTable is empty how come i get message prompts using the above code that give me my data as a result of my query from the database. Anyways i employed your code and its the same null reference exception.

Comment: Then the defective assumption lies after the Fill(). No idea there...can't see that code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i was able to solve my problem by directly executing the query against the tableadapter instead of using separate data adapter

```
        string var = comboBox1.Text;
        contactsTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE " + var + " LIKE " + textBox1.Text + ";");
        contactsTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection;
        contactsTableAdapter.Adapter.Fill(eRPDataSet.Contacts);
```